# How to get a single object by value in AngularJS Factory

Tags: angularjs, json, factory, http-get

How do I get a single object from the flights array? I am first calling the getFlights() function in one view, and then I want to use the getFlight(flightId) in a another view when going to the page for a specific flight.

When I call the getFlight(flightId) however, it contains no data.

```
angular.module('myApp.factories', []).
    factory('flightFactory', function ($http) {

        var flights = {};

        return {
            getFlights: function () {
                return $http.get('app/data/flights.json').then(function (response) {
                    flights = response;
                    return flights;
                });
            },
            getFlight: function (id) {

                for (var i = 0; i < flights.length; i++) {
                    if (flights[i].flightId == id) {
                        return flights[i];
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        };

    });
```

Here is how i get all the flights in the first controller

```
flightFactory.getFlights().then(function(response) {
              $scope.flights = response.data;
});
```

Here is how I have been trying to get a single flight in the second controller

```
$scope.singleflight = flightFactory.getFlight($routeParams.flightID);
```

Here is the content of the JSON file

```
[
{
    "date": "2016-02-18T00:19:11-08:00",
    "numberOfSeats": 30,
    "totalPrice": 610,
    "flightId": "PR6674",
    "travelTime": 422,
    "destination": "South Sudan",
    "origin": "Copenhagen"
},
{
    "date": "2016-11-07T16:35:45-08:00",
    "numberOfSeats": 87,
    "totalPrice": 405,
    "flightId": "ZN4890",
    "travelTime": 196,
    "destination": "Rwanda",
    "origin": "Copenhagen"
},
{
    "date": "2016-07-11T18:05:32-07:00",
    "numberOfSeats": 36,
    "totalPrice": 646,
    "flightId": "AT1096",
    "travelTime": 399,
    "destination": "Equatorial Guinea",
    "origin": "Copenhagen"
}
]
```

Help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jeffery Yu's works, but it exposes the flights array.

```
angular.module('myApp.factories', []).
    factory('flightFactory', function ($http) {

        var flights = {};
        var _this = this;
        return {
            getFlights: function () {
                return $http.get('app/data/flights.json').then(function (response) {
                    _this.flights = response;
                    return _this.flights;
                });
            },
            getFlight: function (id) {
                var flights = _this.flights;
                for (var i = 0; i < flights.length; i++) {
                    if (flights[i].flightId == id) {
                        return flights[i];
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        };

    });
```

this will hide the flights array from the user (no direct access). This is what @Anik Islam Abhi is talking about.

Comment: Thanks. First function works fine, but the getFlight()-function gives an error "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" which is flights.length in the for loop.

Comment: I've added a var in front of "flights" in the second function. I think leaving it out causes the problem.  Is it possible for you to create a simple plunker of your views so we can help with debugging?

Comment: Sir can I invite you to the github repo instead? It's contains quite a lot of files.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with github. I've downloaded your source but got stuck on the login screen when I load the index.html

Comment: I'm sorry, i've not work with java web application so I have no idea on how to run your github project.

Comment: No worries, i'll try to ask my teacher :) thx for your help tho

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('myApp.factories', []).factory('flightFactory', function ($http) {

    return {
        flights:{},
        getFlights: function () {
            return $http.get('app/data/flights.json').then(function (response) {
                this.flights = response;
                return this.flights;
            });
        },
        getFlight: function (id) {

            for (var i = 0; i < flights.length; i++) {
                if (this.flights[i].flightId == id) {
                    return this.flights[i];
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

});
```

Comment: it's better to assing this at the start of method into a variable then work with that variable. this varies from place to place

Comment: Same error here. "TypeError: Cannot set property 'flights' of undefined
    at factories.js:11" which is "this.flights = response;"